# How to get given date format in phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to phone gap.

I want to send date like a specific format to server.

I face problem to get the date format of given string.

For example i get the string like

20/04/2014 or 
04/20/2014 or 
2014/04/20 or 
20 Apr 2014 ....

I mean i get the same date in different formats.i need to convert the date to a specific format,if it it is any format.

If any one know the solution.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Date format must be passed with date string otherwise how could you determine 01/01/2012 is in MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY format?

Answer (score 0):

There is a related plugin ***[cordova-plugin-globalization](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization/blob/master/doc/index.md)***, I'm not sure whether it is what you need, but why not have a try?

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization/blob/master/doc/index.md

Hope this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
    var currentDate = new Date();
    document.write(currentDate);
```

To return the current date.

(OR)

The Hard way...

```
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1;//January is 0, so always add + 1

    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd}
    if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm}
    var today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
    document.write(today);
```

If you used this then you can format the date to the way you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f6k3H/85/)

It will give you in one format. check the fiddle with your example dates.

```
var d = new Date();
var c = new Date('20 Apr 2014');

alert(formatDate(c)); //This will give you proper one format date
alert(formatDate(d)); // This returns today's date

function formatDate(d)
{
   var month = d.getMonth();
   var day = d.getDate();
   month = month + 1;

   month = month + "";

   if (month.length == 1)
   {
       month = "0" + month;
   }

   day = day + "";

   if (day.length == 1)
   {
       day = "0" + day;
   }

   return month + '-' + day + '-' + d.getFullYear();
}
```